# Laravel Passport response from same endpoint at same time with two different access_tokens from two users in both cases return first user

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 5.8 with Passport 7.2 for building API for my application. I am using password_grant for authentication.

I have created everything from registration to login and everything seems to function properly. I am able to get access_token and refresh_token and to access routes that has middleware auth:api attached.

In my routes i have this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
...
    Route::get('test', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user(); 
    });
...
});
```

When i call this /api/test URL with header Authorization: Bearer access_token i am getting currently authenticated user. That just works fine.

I am testing these endpoints with Postman, but everything is same if i test this using javascript from browser.

The problem is when i have two different access_token from two different users. If i call this URL with one access_token i get correct user data as response and if i wait for few seconds and call same URL with second access_token i get correct second user data as response. But if i call this URL two times with these two access_tokens at same time (call first and for example after half second call second) i get first call user data as response in both requests.

I hope you can understand what is problem.

Could this be caching problem, or maybe session problem (even if api is stateless)?

If you need more informations just tell me.

Firstly i thought it was browser cache issue, but it is same in postman. I have also tried to use Google Chrome for one request and Mozilla for second and everything is same.

If you have any idea about what could be wrong i will appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It is not Laravel or Passport problem.

The problem was:
on my server we have Nginx and https://engintron.com/ configured and this Engintron has some micro-caching mechanism.

This micro-cache could be completely disabled or can be disabled with headers in request (Cache-Control: private).

Micro-cache is caching GET request to URL for 1 second and ignoring different Authorization headers. That's why i get same user data for two different Authorization headers if i make these two requests in under 1 second period.

I hope this will help someone else in future. If somebody need more info do not hesitate to contact me :D